# apache-spark: rdd.unpersist crashes for large files

Tags: apache-spark, timeout, large-files

My code runs on EMR, Spark version 2.0.2.
It works fine for smaller files but frequently crashes for files larges than 15GB.
The crash happens in unpersist function, which incidentally is the last step of processing.

Any ideas will be very helpful.
Thanks!

```
    17/05/06 23:46:01 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from /10.0.2.149:56200 is closed
    17/05/06 23:46:01 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Disabling executor 7.
    17/05/06 23:46:01 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 7 (epoch 5)
    17/05/06 23:46:01 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 7 from BlockManagerMaster.
    17/05/06 23:46:01 WARN BlockManagerMaster: Failed to remove RDD 43 - Connection reset by peer
    java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:313)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    17/05/06 23:46:01 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(7, ip-10-0-2-149.eu-west-1.compute.internal, 36043)
    17/05/06 23:46:01 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 7 successfully in removeExecutor
    17/05/06 23:46:01 INFO YarnScheduler: Executor 7 on ip-10-0-2-149.eu-west-1.compute.internal killed by driver.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/mnt/update_hid.py", line 565, in <module>
        process(current_date)
      File "/mnt/update_hid.py", line 517, in process
        get_missing_ip=get_missing_ip)
      File "/mnt/update_hid.py", line 466, in add_migration_info
    17/05/06 23:46:01 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Existing executor 7 has been removed (new total is 11)
        Hid.unpersist()
      File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 251, in unpersist
      File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
      File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o205.unpersist.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.removeRdd(BlockManagerMaster.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.unpersistRDD(SparkContext.scala:1683)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.unpersist(RDD.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.unpersist(JavaRDD.scala:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:313)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        ... 1 more

    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Requesting to kill executor(s) 9
    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Removing executor 9 because it has been idle for 60 seconds (new desired total will be 10)
    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.2.182:4040
    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Interrupting monitor thread
    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO SchedulerExtensionServices: Stopping SchedulerExtensionServices
    (serviceOption=None,
     services=List(),
     started=false)
    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
    17/05/06 23:46:02 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?